# ¿Como remover un elemento de la posición indicada?

Tags: javascript

Implementar el método `removeFromPos` dentro del `prototype` de `LinkedList` que deberá remover un elemento de la posición indicada (`pos` será la posición del elemento a remover).

En el caso de que la posición en la que se quiera hacer el `remove` no sea válida (Supere el tamaño de la lista actual o sea un número negativo) debe devolver `false`.

Si el nodo fue removido correctamente devolver el valor del nodo.

Aclaración: la posición cero corresponde al `head` de la `LinkedList`

- Ejemplo 1:
  Suponiendo que la lista actual es:

  ```
  // Head --> [1] --> [2] --> [3] --> [4]

  lista.removeFromPos(2);
  ```

  Ahora la lista quedaría:

  ```
  Head --> [1] --> [2] --> [4]
  ```

  y la función debería haber devuelto el valor 3
- Ejemplo 2:

  Suponiendo que se pide una posición inválida:

  ```
  removeFromPos(8) --> false
  ```

Mi código:

```
LinkedList.prototype.removeFromPos = function(pos) {

  pos = this.head;
  if (!pos) return false;
  if (!pos.next) {
    this.head = null;
    this.length--;
    return pos.value;
  };
  var resultado;
  while (pos.next.next) {
    pos = pos.next;
  }
  resultado = pos.next;
  pos.next = null
  this.length--;
  return resultado.value;
}
```

Lo único que me falta es que cuando le pase una posición que no existe me retorne `false`.

¿Me podrían ayudar para ver como lo puedo implementar?.
Gracias

Comment: Tu función `removeFromPos` no deberia funcionar ya que estas pisando la variable `pos` en la primer línea. Todo lo demás tampoco tiene sentido. No te lo tomes mal, pero ¿estas seguro de que intentaste resolverlo?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la longitud **this.length** para determinar si el indice es válido, es decir, si **pos** (sumandole 1) es mayor a la longitud entonces es inválido. Se le suma 1 a pos para tener en cuenta que pueden indicar como **pos** 0 pero para calcular facilmente con respecto a la longitud, es mejor que sea 1.

Por ejemplo: si indican la **pos** 4 y tenemos 4 elementos entonces no es válido, porque pos + 1 es 5, esto es asi porque si quieres acceder al indice [4] no se podría ya que hay 4 elementos y índice máximo es 3.

Luego para el negativo basta con ver si es menor que cero (0)

```
if((pos + 1) > this.length || pos < 0)
 return false;
```

Comment: Y donde lo pondria en el codigo que tengo porque eso es lo unico que me falta, que me retorne false si no hay elementos suficientes o si no existe

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que hay algo mal en tu codigo.

```
LinkedList.prototype.removeFromPos = function(pos) {

  pos = this.head;
  if (!pos) return false;
  if (!pos.next) {
    this.head = null;
    this.length--;
    return pos.value;
  };
  var resultado;
  while (pos.next.next) {
    pos = pos.next;
  }
  resultado = pos.next;
  pos.next = null
  this.length--;
  return resultado.value;
}
```

En la primera linea vos estas reemplazando tu variable `pos` por una referencia al primer elemento de la lista enlazada. Fijate que despues usas cosas como next que tiene sentido en el contexto de un nodo.

Recomendaria encararlo por otro lado. Vos sabes que siempre empezas desde 0 verdad? Y tenes tambien una referencia al primer nodo. Lo que yo haria es empezar a iterar la lista (pidiendo siempre el next del nodo)
Declara una variable donde vayas guardando siempre el nodo que estas viendo en ese momento (inicializada como `nodo = this.head` y en las siguientes interaciones va a ser `nodo = nodo.next`)
Una vez que llegues al indice donde `indice == pos` entonces llegaste a tu nodo! (hablemos del caso que pos supera la longitud de la lista luego) El nodo va a ser el que tenes referenciado en la variable `nodo`.

Entonces aca te tenes que ocupar de dos cosas

1. Devolver el valor del nodo
2. Eliminar el nodo de la lista

Para el punto 1, es facil guardate el valor de nodo.value en una variable que despues lo vamos a devolver

Para el punto 2, lo que tenemos que hacer es desreferenciar el nodo de la lista. Para eso lo que tenemos que hacer es

1. Decirle al nodo anterior a tu nodo que ahora el siguiente va a ser el proximo de tu nodo.
2. Referenciar el NEXT de tu nodo a null, asi no te quedan referencias perdidas.

Y listo! Tu nodo no esta mas en tu estructura, porque a nivel memoria no existe mas una referencia a ese nodo.

Para el caso en el que la posicion no exista, lo que podes hacer es, si al final de tu ciclo no encontras el nodo (acordate que tu ciclo termina cuando tu nodoActual.next = null) entonces devolves false. esto lo podes hacer con un while (nodo.next != null)

Si necesitas ayuda con el codigo avisame y lo hacemos, pero esta bueno entender los conceptos de estructuras de datos y saber volcarlos a codigo. Cuando te salen estos ejercicios es super placentero.

Espero haber ayudado!

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene varios errores, más allá de no devolver *false* cuando el índice es incorrecto.

- Para comenzar, en la primera línea pierdes el valor que te pasaron en el parámetro `pos`. Ya de allí, se hace imposible encontrar el elemento a eliminar, pues no hay forma de recuperar ese parámetro. Necesitas declarar y utilizar una variable distinta para ir recorriendo la lista.
- Dado que tienes almacenada la longitud de la lista, se hace trivial hacer la validación de si la posición es inválida, que es básicamente si el valor pasado es negativo o si sobrepasa la longitud de la lista.

  En este punto es importante que te detengas a reflexionar sobre en qué momento es inválido el valor recibido en ese extremo. Primero debemos recordar que lo que recibimos es el índice del elemento a eliminar.

  Digamos que tu tienes una lista con 1 elemento, ¿qué índice tiene ese elemento? (Ya que lo que te están pasando es el índice).

  Si tu tienes una lista con 10 elementos, ¿cuál es el índice del último elemento?.

  De este análisis debe desprenderse la comparación que vas a hacer entre el índice y tu variable `this.length` para determinar si continuar a una búsqueda o devolver *falso*. ¿Si `pos` es mayor a `this.length`? ¿Si es mayor o igual? ¿si es menor?. Esto debes decidirlo tú de acuerdo al análisis. Una vez lo escribas, escribir el código es trivial, digamos que decides que es inválido si  `pos` es menor a `this.length`, entonces

  ```
  if (pos < this.length) return false;
  ```

  Hará el *trabajo sucio*.
- Luego lo básico pareces tener ya una idea, que es ir recorriendo la lista, pero tu lógica está fallando en cómo dejarla funcional luego de extraer el elemento.

  Tú mismo has puesto en la descripción del problema una lista inicial y cómo debe quedar al eliminar el elemento con índice 2. Pero creo que solo la copiaste de la descripción del problema y no te has sentado a analizar detenidamente lo que pasa con las *flechas* entre estos elementos, trataré de ayudarte con esto:

  Suponiendo que la lista actual es:

  ```
  Head --> [1] --> [2] --> [3] --> [4]
  ```

  Al hacer `lista.removeFromPos(2);` debe pasar lo siguiente:

  - Primero vamos recorriendo la lista hasta identificar el nodo anterior al que tenemos que eliminar. Dado que sabemos el índice de dicho nodo, es algo que yo haría con un ciclo for (ya sé que no me voy a salir de la lista por el extremo, porque he validado antes la longitud).

  ```
  Head --> [1] --> [2] --> [3] --> [4]
            ^       ^
            0       1
  ```

  - Almacenamos en una variable auxiliar o temporal el nodo que vamos a eliminar, pues ya no lo podremos acceder mediante la lista.

  ```
  Head --> [1] --> [2] --> [3] --> [4]
            ^       ^       ^
            0       1       |
                            --- aEliminar
  ```

  - Luego, hacemos que el nodo anterior apunte hacia el nodo siguiente del que vamos a eliminar

  ```
  .                       /---\
  Head --> [1] --> [2] --/ [3] \--> [4]
            ^       ^       ^
            0       1       |
                            --- aEliminar
  ```

  Y ahora si, la lista quedaría ya así:

  ```
  Head --> [1] --> [2] --> [4]
  ```
- Un caso especial dónde esto que he descrito no va a funcionar por si solo, es si te piden eliminar el primer elemento (el índice 0), pues no hay un nodo anterior. Para eliminarlo de la lista, tenemos que almacenarlo en nuestra variable temporal y cambiar a dónde apunta `this.head`, que tendría que ser, como antes, al siguiente elemento del que se va a eliminar.
- Para que el programa funcione, entonces, haces algo como

  ```
  if (condiciones de validación) return false;
  let aEliminar;
  if (pos === 0) {
    aEliminar = this.head;
    this.head = aEliminar.next;
  } else {
    //la lógica para _eliminar_ cualquier otro elemento
  }
  this.length--;
  return aEliminar.value;
  ```
- En este momento ya podemos retornar el valor del elemento que tenemos almacenado en la variable auxiliar `aEliminar`.

No puedo escribirte el código, pues en realidad el objetivo de estos ejercicios es que reflexiones y analices sobre el funcionamiento de las estructuras. Cuándo has comprendido los conceptos, el código sale solito, de manera muy trivial.

Si te lo doy escrito (o cualquier otro), lo copias, lo pegas, y mañana tenemos otro dolor de cabeza en la oficina con un programador que no tiene idea de lo que pasa.

Una oportunidad de mejora, es que el *profe* aquí no te pidió hacer otras validaciones que son lógicas. En el parámetro te pueden pasar otros valores incorrectos, como un negativo, o incluso datos no numéricos. Podrias agregar esas validaciones también en la misma condición a evaluar para retornar falso.

Otro tema para reflexionar es que yo he dicho antes que el algorítmo funcionará con todos los elementos de la lista (incluso el último). ¿estoy en lo correcto?